# "events" for GA4 not seen when loaded through tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

We've added GA4 to our sites using a GTM GA4 Configuration tag, this is working perfectly for the standard tracking.

However we also want to fire some custom events via the `gtag('event', $eventName, $options)` method. These don't track at all.

If we first call `gtag('config', 'G-......')` then subsiquent `gtag('event', ...)`  calls do work but we get a duplicate `page_view` and also loose any custom parameters we have set. It feels like this removes the point of using GTM really as it also requires the ID to be in site code and not configured through GTM. It also feels like it's just a config issue not a fundimental issue with loading GA4 via GTM and wanting to send not GMT proxied events.

My guess is that the GTM implementation is different and doesn't register the same configuration as if you had loaded it with `gtag.js` and called `gtag('config', ...`.

I'd prefer not to have to set up each event as a GTM event either as I want to be able to pass any data across from from the front end.

Is it possible to get

- `gtag('event', ...)` calls to pass to GA as if `gtag('config', ...` had been called
- Config a GTA trigger/tag that would pass through the raw data to GA4

Comment: if you already use GTM, why do you still try sending events through gtag directly? Isn't it much easier to have all analytics within GTM?

Comment: @BNazaruk we have Js code generating dynamic events that we push to the data layer. If there is a way to proxy that event directly then that would be perfect but AFAIK we'd need to map every event type individually in order to pass across the parameters.

Comment: depends on the structure of your DL events, but most likely, everything can be done in one tag in GTM. Especially considering the power of custom JS variables in GTM.